# What's the meaningful way when I mean that all are included? of first to fifth, of first up to fifth or from first to fifth?

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, numbers

He doesn't want to transfer students of first to fifth grades to remote learning.

He doesn't want to transfer students from first to fifth grades to remote learning.

He doesn't want to transfer students of first up to fifth grades to remote learning.

What's the meaningful way of expressing the thought when I mean that all from first up to fifth are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He doesn't want to transfer students **from** first **through** fifth grades to remote learning.

***from*** (a fixed source) → ***through*** (continuing on the same path) → ***to*** (destination)

You can consider using the above sentence. It represents the numbers (grades in this case) from 1 to 5. However it is less ambiguous as compared to *"from first to fifth [..]"*, because people might think that you are hinting of transferring students from 1st grade to 5th grade (I think people won't think in this way, but you never know!)

> He doesn't want to transfer students **of** first **up to** fifth grades to remote learning.
>
> He doesn't want to transfer students **of** first **to** fifth grades to remote learning.

***of*** (showing possession i.e students belonging to grades 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) → ***to/up to*** (showing the range) → ***to*** (destination)

This two statements are acceptable and unambiguous as compared to the following one:

> He doesn't want to transfer students **from** first **to** fifth grades to remote learning.